# How to properly set a "full LaTeX" figure in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to plot my figures in "full LaTeX" so that it fits to the TeX document where it is implemented. But as I have many plots, I wondered if it possible to pre-set default values ONCE so that :

- axes labels,
- numbers on the axes,
- title,
- legend,
- text,

are in the latex font - without having to use `set` no more in the whole Matlab session. In addition, to get rid of the `\bf{}` in the `xlabel`, `ylabel` and `title` (I prefere them to be bold, including math symbols if some are present), is there a way to automatically "bold" them ?

I already managed to get a plot with labels and title in Latex. But axes numbers and legend are still in original font. And the tex intrepeter ignores the `bold`command.

```
set(0,'DefaultTextInterpreter','latex')
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontWeight','Bold')
set(0,'DefaultAxesLineWidth',3)
set(0,'DefaultTextFontWeight','Bold')
set(0,'DefaultAxesTitle','Bold')
set(0,'DefaultTextFontSize',35)
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontSize',30)
set(0,'DefaultLineLineWidth',3) % for big boxes
```

How do I set the legend and the axes-numbers interpreters ? Any way to automatically get bold labels and title ? Because implementing directly the `\bf{}`will return an error if there is some math e.g. `xlabel(\bf{position} \boldmath{$x$} \bf{(mm)})` (which is a heavy notation).

EDIT 1 : MATLAB version R2016-b

Comment: By axes numbers, do you mean axes ticks? By labels, you mean axis labels (xlabel / ylabel) or axis tick labels (xticklabel/yticklabel)?

Comment: @SardarUsama I mean the ticks (e.g. for a plot where `x=0:10` the x axis has the ticks 1,2,3...10 in normal font, in that code.

Comment: This might be a version dependent issue. It tried and it seems to work fine in V2018b.